# ValueError: malformed node or string:

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which one of its columns is a composed of a list containing 2 lists like this :`[['emha'], [30, 25, 0.00614052, 55, 3046]]` which in process of saving to excel file has got to string format and I used the`.applymap(literal_eval)` from `ast` package to convert it back to list but now probably because I have decimals in my list it gives `ValueError: malformed node or string: [['emha'], [30, 25, 0.00614052, 55, 3046]]` error, how to fix it?

Comment: try `df.astype(str).applymap(literal_eval)`

Comment: However tempting it may be to use a complicated data structure in pandas dataframe, it won't give you any value in terms of performance or comprehensibility. Also, the problem might be because you might be saving it as a CSV (comma-separated values).

Comment: @Anurag Dabas it worked thank you so much if you want make it an answer

Comment: @FarhangAmaji Thanks but It is not necessary....Happy coding ***:)***